# Theoretical Magnetic Monopole (USAPHO 2012)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, integration

I'm trying to solve question B2 on the 2012 USAPHO semifinal exam ([page 14](https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2019/upload/USAPhO-2012-Solutions.pdf)). The solutions are here on pages 15-16.

I can follow everything until the last line on page 15:

The change in speed in one trip is

$$
\Delta v \approx \frac1v\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a\,dx = \frac1v \int_0^{\pi}a 
\dfrac {dx}{d\theta}\,d\theta = -\dfrac bv\int_0^{\pi}\dfrac{a}{\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta
$$

What is $\dfrac {dx}{d\theta}$ and how did it become $\dfrac{b}{\sin^2\theta}$ in the last step? I'm having a hard time visualizing the integration in spherical coordinates. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With these spherical coordinates, you may want to think of the $x$-axis as vertical, as $\theta$ is the angle with respect to the $x$-axis. We use the substitution from part a:
$$\theta=\arctan(b/x)$$
$$\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{b}{b^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Now, if $\tan{\theta}=b/x$, we have $\sin{\theta}=b/\sqrt{b^2+x^2}$, which you can see by drawing a triangle. Then, rearranging,
$$\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{b}{\sin^2{\theta}}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! That made perfect sense.